# How to share objects between api routes and getServerSideProps?

Tags: next.js

### Problem

I'm creating a simple tic-tac-toe game.

I wanted to access a shared object from `getServerSideProps` but it's empty.

The `matches` array in `new-match.js` seems to be a different object than in `match.jsx`, although both run on the backend.

### Code

I have a file with an array:

`match.js`

```js
export const matches = []
```

Route for creating a match:

`pages/api/new-match.js`

```js
import { matches } from '@/matches';

export default function handler(req, res) {
  const { id } = randomUUID();
  matches.push(id)
  res.redirect(301, `/match?id=${id}`);
}
```

And a match page:

`pages/match.jsx`

```js
import { matches } from '@/matches';

export default function Match() {
  // ...
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { id } = context.query;

  const match = matches[id];

  if (!match) {
    return {
      props: {},
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
};
```